# FTP Server with database driven content?

Tags: .net, ftp

Our organization currently has an external customer website that allows customers to download files that are created for them. There tends to be some shifting in the security, so the files the customer sees are based upon a database of which accounts can see what files. The files are stored on the secure side of our network, and web services are used to get the files from the internal file server, and streamed to the web response.

The challenge is to provide the customers with the ability to use an FTP client to download these files. There are some FTP servers that provide a mechanism for custom authentication, but none so far that can serve virtual / custom file lists (most virtual directories are just virtual mappings to other file server locations).

Is the idea of creating an FTP interface to our authentication and file database seem like overkill, or are there any products that would meet our needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP protocol is actually quite simple.  It is not too tough to roll your own server if you don't find anything pre-packaged:

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html

Answer (score 0):

There are several FTP server libraries and open source FTP servers.

[Open Source FTP Server in Java](http://cftp.coldcore.com/) that is nicely extensible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very well designed FTP server written in C# here: http://www.csharphelp.com/archives3/archive524.html